# Visual Studio Code - error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code (VS Code) Editor for ASP.NET Core-5 Web API.

I have installed different packages in the VS Code without any error.

However, when I did:

> dotnet run

I got this errors:

> C:\Users\Kume\source\repos\MyApp\DDM.API.Core\API.Core.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

> C:\Users\Kume\source\repos\MyApp\DDM.API.Core\API.Core.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

> C:\Users\Kume\source\repos\MyApp\DDM.API.Core\API.Core.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

> C:\Users\Kume\source\repos\MyApp\DDM.API.Core\API.Core.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

How do I resolve this?

Comment: It would appear that nuget.org is not among your NuGet sources. What happens when you run `dotnet nuget list source`? Did you change any NuGet settings? Are using Nuget.Config somewhere? What happens when you `dotnet restore`? See also [Common nuget configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses) at MS doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best option is to create a Nuget.config file at the root of your solution and place the following content inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
      <clear /> <!-- (optional) this is for clear sources like default Offline repo -->
      <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have three projects in the Solution. Do I put it in each project or the solution as a whole?

Comment: In solution is better, cause apply for all projects

Comment: If you are copying the XML shared by @OsniPezziniJunior, either strip the comment or correct it from <!- (optional) this is for clear sources like default Offline repo -> to  <!-- (optional) this is for clear sources like default Offline repo -->. It worked like a charm from me after I did this.