# how to resolve [NU1101] Unable to find package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, rider

When building a C# project in JetBrains Rider, I get this error:
`[NU1101] Unable to find package Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.NET5. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org`

I also get the same issue in Visual Studio and I can't figure out the solution. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Tried some of the solutions in [how to resolve "Unable to find package" nuget error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376567/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-package-nuget-error), but they didn't work. Also tried [Visual Studio Code - error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138533/visual-studio-code-error-nu1101-unable-to-find-package-microsoft-entityframew) but to no avail

Comment: When I search for that package on NuGet.org, I get no results: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.NET5. Is this an internal package? Have you checked your package sources configuration? In VisualStudio (full, not Code), you can find this under Tools / Options / NuGet Package Manager / Package Sources.